# Node.js reload template with data

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, qr-code

I basically need to have the following:

1. Browser reads a QR-Code over the webcam
2. The content is sent to the index page with a `ajax post`
3. The Node.js backend should process this data and display the result again on the index page

Here is the code:

`index.ejs`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><%= title %></title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/instascan.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div style="display: none;">
                <video id="preview" style="display: none;"></video>
            </div>
            <div class="qrcode" id="qrcode"><%= qrcode %></div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                scanner = new Instascan.Scanner({video: document.getElementById('preview')});
                scanner.addListener('scan', function(content) {
                    console.log(content);
                    $.post('/', { qrcode: content }, function (data, status) {
                        //console.log(status);
                    });
                });
                Instascan.Camera.getCameras().then(function (cameras) {
                    if (cameras.length > 0) {
                        scanner.start(cameras[0]);
                    } else {
                        console.error('No Cameras found!');
                        alert('No Cameras found!');
                    }
                }).catch(function (e) {
                    console.error(e);
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

`indes.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express', qrcode: '' });
});

router.post('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.qrcode);
  res.render('index', {
      title: 'Express',
      qrcode: req.body.qrcode
  });

});

module.exports = router;
```

How can I reload the index page displaying the content of the QR-code (`req.body.qrcode`)?

---

UPDATE:
I tried to use a `GET` instead of a `POST` as mentioned in the comment. So `index.js` is now

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    qrcode = '';

    if (req.query.qrcode) {
        qrcode = decodeURIComponent(req.query.qrcode);
    }

    res.render('index', { title: 'Express', qrcode: qrcode });
    console.log(req.query);
});
```

(ajax get is also updated accordingly, i.e., I receive a valid GET request). Somehow the rendering does not happen the second time.

Comment: The scanner listener has to perform get request now instead of post.

Answer (score 1):

From a post request, the browser does not render a new page. You can either send a res.redirect to another "get" endpoint, that renders the result page, or you can change the router.post route to router.get and pass the qrcode as a query param '/?qrcode=...'

Comment: Thank you. I have now tried to use a GET request instead, but somehow it still does not work (see EDIT above) @justadudewhohacks

Comment: the GET request gets logged successfully with (GET /?qrcode=Yes%20I%20have%20successfully%20read%20a%20QR-Code). also, when I enter this get manually, it works

Answer (score 0):

After trying with a `GET` request I went back to a `POST` and using the `success` parameter there. That way I an easily send back the response from the backend.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({qrcode: content}),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: '/',
    success: function(data) {
        document.getElementById('qrcode').innerHTML = data;
    }
});
```